# Mac crashed, python won't import any packages now

Tags: python, permissions, anaconda

My mac crashed while Jupyter Notebook was open, and now I import basic libraries like Pandas or Numpy. I tried reinstalling those but to no avail.

When I tried conda install anaconda or conda update --all and I get this error

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::qt-5.9.6-h45cd832_2'.
PermissionError(1, 'Operation not permitted')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/jerry/anaconda3/bin/Assistant.app/Contents/PkgInfo' -> '/Users/jerry/anaconda3/bin/Assistant.app/Contents/PkgInfo.c~'
```

Answer (score 0):

It says `Operation not permitted`. You should try running the command with sudo to see if elevated privileges can fix the issue.